# How many ways can you distribute k different items among n different people if all the items must be shared between r people?

Tags: combinatorics

I understand how many ways there are to distribute $k$ different items among $n$ different people with no restrictions ($n^k$), but if you had to share each item among $r$ people, what effect would that have?

I imagined that for each item you pick up, choosing $r$ people could go down in $\binom{n}{r}$ ways, so the total number of things that could effectively happen would be $k\binom{n}{r}$. Alas, I think I am wrong. How can I rethink this problem?

Here's an example of one and the solution given that I can't get my head around:

Ex: How many ways can you distribute $4$ presents among $8$ people $A, B, ... H$ if all the presents must be shared between $2$ people?

The solution given was: $28 \times 14 = 392$

Can anyone help me to understand this?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{8}{2}=28$ ways to choose $2$ people out of $8$ and there are $2^4-2=14$ ways to distribute the $4$ presents over $2$ people , such that no person gets all presents.

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate it!